Snap not connecting to internal MS Surface Pro 5 cameras
Running Ubuntu 22.04.4 with the Linux 6.8.6-surface kernel. I'm trying to make my cameras connect to Telegram-desktop. But Telegram doesn't even seem to be aware cameras are an option. Telegram should have permission to view my cameras, and I've confirmed that snap connections telegram-desktop returns a line of telegram-desktop:camera    :camera and conversely, snap interface camera returns plugs: - telegram-desktop.
I can access my cameras in Cheese, so I know they're at least theoretically functional. How do I connect the cameras to snap?
